# FirebaseError: The operation 'put' cannot be performed on a root reference, create a non-root reference using child, such as .child('file.png')

Tags: javascript, firebase, file-upload, firebase-storage

I want to upload an image to firebase and get back the image url. Below is the code that I have written but I'm getting an error:

```
FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: The operation 'put' cannot be performed on a root reference, create a non-root reference using child, such as .child('file.png'). (storage/invalid-root-operation)
```

```js
const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
    try {
      storageRef.put(file).on(
        "state_changed",
        (snap) => {
          let percentage = (snap.bytesTransferred / snap.totalBytes) * 100;
          setProgress(percentage);
        },
        (err) => {
          setError(err);
        },
        async () => {
          const url = await storageRef.getDownloadURL();
          setUrl(url);
        }
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I have pretty much the same code, but when I create the reference I pass the path as a parameter. Otherwise, by default points to the root bucket, hence the exception.

Try changing your first line for:

```
const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(file.name);
```

From the documentation:

```
/**
 * Returns a reference for the given path in the default bucket.
 * @param path A relative path to initialize the reference with,
 *     for example `path/to/image.jpg`. If not passed, the returned reference
 *     points to the bucket root.
 * @return A reference for the given path.
 */
ref(path?: string): firebase.storage.Reference;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```
storage().ref(`newfolder/${whateverYouAreUploading.name}`)
```